# JavaScript function not defined in HTML-document, why not?

Tags: javascript

I am coding a program that lets a user put in a telephone number and tell the user if it's accepted / denied based on a few conditions. 
I've worked out the function that does the calculation, but I can't get the JavaScript to work with the HTML-document: it doesn't get found.

Here are the two codes: (JS then HTML):

```
function testanummer(nummer){
    nummer = document.getElementById("a").value;
    if isNaN(nummer){
        console.log("Hi! This phone number appears faulty, please try again.");
    } else if (nummer.length <=8) && else if (nummer.length >=14) {
        console.log("Thanks! We'll be in touch shortly.");
    } else {
        console.log("Hi! This phone number appears faulty, please try again.");
    }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Uppgift nummer 5</title>

    <script src="testanummer.js"></script>
</head> 


<body>
    <form>
        <label for="a">Skriv in ditt telefonnummer här: </label>
        <input type="text" name="nummer" id="a">
        <input type = "button" value ="Testa telefonnummer" onclick="testanummer(nummer);">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why it doesn't work? I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

and:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: testanummer is not defined

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your "nummer" variable in your `onclick` event is undefined. Change it to `onclick="testanummer(this.value)"`. Or remove the `nummer` from the function parameter and just call `testanummer()` since you retrieve the entered number in your function anyway.

Comment: The function is not defined because you have syntax errors. The error message will tell you where (you have to wrap all conditions for `if` statements into parenthesis, like so: `if (isNaN(nummer))`).

Comment: Your JS is malformed, is that the exact contents of testanumer.js  ?

Comment: you're missing the last `}` from the javascript file to close the function, hence the syntax error. This means the file cannot be parsed, hence the ReferenceError.

Comment: LOL human code parsers :)

Comment: In the future, go here http://jsfiddle.net/ paste your javascript in and hit the jslint button to see some of the issues.

Answer (score 4):

There are two syntax errors in the code. The first syntax error is here:

```
if isNaN(nummer){
```

It should be:

```
if (isNaN(nummer)) {
```

The second syntax error is in this line:

```
} else if (nummer.length <=8) && else if (nummer.length >=14) {
```

The syntax should be:

```
} else if (nummer.length <= 8  && nummer.length >= 14) {
```

However, it seems that you got the conditions backwards, I think this is what you mean:

```
} else if (nummer.length >= 8  && nummer.length <= 14) {
```

When calling the function, you should get the value from the textbox, not just a reference to it. Also, not all browsers put input fields in the global scope, use the form to access the field:

```
<input type = "button" value ="Testa telefonnummer" onclick="testanummer(this.form.nummer.value);">
```

Then you can skip the assignment of the `nummer` variable in the function.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yes, I just noticed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Two errors:

```
} else if ((nummer.length <=8) && else if (nummer.length >=14)) {
```

Change it to (even though your condition is wrong... Shorter than 8 AND longer than 14?):

```
} else if ((nummer.length <=8) && (nummer.length >=14)) {
```

And you have an error in the `onclick` eventhandler:

```
onclick="testanummer(nummer);"
```

Should be:

```
onclick="testanummer(this.form.nummer.value);"
```

or if delete the argument from the function (since you retrieve it within the function anyway) even :

```
onclick="testanummer();"
```

So your final .js file should be:

```
function testanummer(nummer){
    nummer = document.getElementById("a").value;
    if (isNaN(nummer)) {
        console.log("Hi! This phone number appears faulty, please try again.");
    } else if ((nummer.length <=8) && (nummer.length >=14)) {  //HAVE A LOOK AT THIS CONDITION
        console.log("Thanks! We'll be in touch shortly.");
    } else {
        console.log("Hi! This phone number appears faulty, please try again.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot a pair of parentheses... This code won’t compile either.

Comment: I have done what you said and I understand the logic behind it but the error is still there.

Comment: @Martijn Yeh I overlooked that. Changed.